# Please recommend a free stealth remote access solution for internal network

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, vnc

I need to have ability to stealthfully access, view, and control a few dozen PC's on my company's network.  I would need a control panel window, so I can instantly connect to any of the users.  Please recommend a secure solution, that will not  make us vulnerable to viruses and hackers.  All of the PC's have dynamic IP addresses, so I may have to use the DNS name or have a solution that uses web.

Answer (score 4):

You can use UltraVNC for this, and set up an icon for each computer.  It can access the computers by hostname or IP address (IPv4 and IPv6 are both supported), and you can use "view-only" mode (which doesn't effect the mouse or keyboard on the server-side {you are the client when connecting to another computer}) or the regular "full control" mode (which allows you to control the mouse and keyboard).

UltraVNC also provides some options for blanking the server's screen and/or disabling mouse/keyboard movements by its user, and for "stealth mode" you can add a parameter in UltraVNC's .ini file to hide the icon entirely from the System Tray (so the user won't even see it in their list of icons that they can show/hide in their "display only these icons" option in their Start Menu properties).

UltraVNC
  http://www.ultravnc.org/

UltraVNC is free, open source software.

For security, it supports encryption.  Unfortunately everything connected to other computers (especially over the internet) are at risk of attack from dark hacking, viruses, SpyWare, etc.  You can't prevent the attempts, but you can do things to reduce the effectiveness of those attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [rautor](http://www.unix.gr/rautor/) can be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to give more information about the "stealth" requirement.  A user will be able to tell that VNC is running, whether or not you connect.  Whether this jeopardizes your mission or not is up to you, since we don't know your use case.

When I was doing employee investigations I used [Atlier AWRC](http://www.atelierweb.com/rcomm/index.htm), with an anonymous service account preconfigured in a domain group that had access to all of the PCs.  A user will still be able to see in the windows event log that the service account logged in, but that has never been a problem for me.

If you need to get full information on what's going on with as much stealth as is possible, I would recommend Spector (Pro, CNE, or 360 depending on what you need).  But test this in a lab before using it in a live investigation -- I have had some close calls with it.